# pub/sub nservicebus beginner

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to get a simple NServiceBus pub/sub working.  Here is what I am trying to do.
I am trying to read a message from msmq, and pub publishes the messages to sub, and the sub will insert the messages to sub's queue.  (right now, there are all on same computer).

I have a pub and a sub (there are Written as console apps).  I also have a Message class, and here it is.

```
    [Serializable]
public class Message : IEvent
{
    public string name { get; set; }

}

public interface IEvent : IMessage
{
    string name { get; set; }

}
```

And, this is my pub

```
            IBus bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(true)
               .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
            .CreateBus().
            Start();
```

sub looks same execpt that it has  .LoadMessageHandlers().

I understand that you have to handle the message, where do you put the Handle() on sub side?  I want to read them and put them into sub's queue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Publisher will handle putting messages in the Subscriber's queue.  To handle those messages, you must implement the IHandleMessages<T> interface on a class in your subscriber.  NSB will execute the Handle method on that class when a message of that type shows up.  For example:

```
public class MyMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<Message>;
{
    // do stuff here 
}
```